# Remove "democratic, community-driven process" from the site not found page

Tags: feature-request, area-51

This is a followup on [Remove "democratic, community-driven process" from the Area 51 FAQ](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18609/remove-democratic-community-driven-process-from-the-area-51-faq).

On the site not found page (e.g. http://pandas.stackexchange.com/) this is still claimed:

> You can vote for it to be created through our democratic, community-driven process at area51.stackexchange.com

Please remove this from the site not found page for the same reason it has been removed from the Area 51 FAQ.