# Remove 'democratically' from sites' help/on-topic page

Tags: feature-request, area-51, help-center-proposed

Rationale: [Remove "democratic, community-driven process" from the Area 51 FAQ](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18609/remove-democratic-community-driven-process-from-the-area-51-faq).

Currently, on each site's `help/on-topic` page:

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for $sitename$, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area51, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

Proposed change:

> If your question is not specifically on-topic for $sitename$, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may commit to or propose a new site at Area51, the place where new Stack Exchange communities are created.

Related: [Remove "democratic, community-driven process" from the site not found page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245040/remove-democratic-community-driven-process-from-the-site-not-found-page)

Comment: It isn't particularly useful to propose a change without explaining why you think this change is beneficial to the community. **Why** do you want this? What makes it valuable? What is wrong with the word "democratic" in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the problem.  "Democratic" doesn't mean "no restrictions".  Democracies can have laws limiting who can vote, who can stand for election, what criteria must be met to get a petition or candidate onto the ballot, and more.  Further, democracies can limit the results even if a majority supports the initiative; a ballot initiative for the government to provide every child with a pony wouldn't be implemented, most likely, no matter how many people voted for it.  Sometimes, cases end up before the court to settle.

When it comes to Area 51, SE is somewhere between a board of elections and a court.  Within those limits, all users who qualify have the same chance to move a proposal forward.